# Procedure of finding accumulation points of set

Tags: general-topology, limsup-and-liminf

For example, there is a set $R$ and  I want to find all accumulation point(or to show, that they don't exist) of $Z$(integers)

I am familiar with concepts of open/closed balls, neighbourhood, $\epsilon$ - neighbourhood, interior pointm open/closed sets, accumulation points.

But I don't know the mechanism of proving(finding/showing), that these points exists or not for subset.

Can you provide me a procedure, describing each step?

Comment: Is your question you want to find the accumulation points of a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness I mean all accumulation points of Z.

Comment: Pick a point $x$ in $R$. For each $\epsilon>0$, consider interval of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $r$. Do all such intervals contain an integer (excluding $x$ if $x$ is an integer)?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ and its subsets have the same accumulation points

Comment: @angryavian of course not. But how can we show this formally?

Comment: @RobertJMcGinness i mean, that i want to find accumulation points of Z, which is subset of R.
Sure, that Z doesn't have accumulation points, but how can we show it?

Comment: Use the definition of accumulation point as angryavian suggested.  Every neighborhood of radius > 0 should contain a point of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Use a contradiction or counterexample to disprove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about an extreme example.  Let A = {1} $\subset \mathbb{R}$.  What are the limit points of A.  Extend this to any finite set of integers, then to all integers

EDIT: 
proof by contradiction

suppose x $\in \mathbb{R}$ and x is an accumulation point of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a point of p $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that p $\not=$ x and |x - p| $\lt \epsilon$...

find an $\epsilon$ that does not work

Comment: I think, I got it. Thank you very much:)